# What's the best way to track if a checkbox / button was clicked in MongoDB?

Tags: html, node.js, angular, mongodb, mongoose

I'll try and make this as short as I can, as I think this is a pretty simple task and I don't know why I'm struggling with it.

I need to make a simple '`task tracking`' website - the rows are the tasks, inserted to and read from `MongoDB`, and the columns are months. The idea is that the cells will be `checkboxes` to be able to track what was clicked, so other users will know when a task was completed.

Now I know I need to run some sort of function when the `checkbox` is clicked, but what's the best way of storing it in the `database` so that whenever the table is updated, the tasks that were already finished will stay ticked? Is this even a good way of doing it?

If anyone's got any suggestions besides the solutions, I'd be open to hearing them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming each checkbox is related to a document stored in MongoDB, you would need MongoDB streams that allow realtime updates. https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/an-introduction-to-change-streams otherwise each time the checkbox is checked or unchecked, you would have to make another call to the API and other users would not be updated of the changes until a refresh. Even worse, the users could be making changes at the same time yielding unexpected results.

Implementing this with MongoDB is complex especially with Angular and TypeScript. If you feel compelled, you could also utilize web sockets such as [Socket.io](https://socket.io/). A solution that I have found for this functionality with easier implementation is a service like Firebase and @angular/fire or Amazon Elasticache.

Comment: I actually was considering using sockets. It isn't supposed to be a heavy duty website by any means, just for a small group (about 3-4 people ish) to track tasks that are supposed to happen on a monthly basis.

EDIT: Another solution I thought of is to track each task per month, and then have an option to add new months or whatever with a button through some kind of admin console.

Comment: A smaller project could benefit from Firebase because you don’t have to worry about a server and it has Auth baked in. The learning curve isn’t nearly as steep as sockets or streams. You’ll be able to get live data in one line of code rather than having to build a whole server-side application.